# git, show list of files if somebody clone particular tag

Tags: git, file

I have a git repo. Some commits have been done - some files added, some deleted.

I want to get list of files, which will be cloned if somebody will clone particular tag from my repository.

So it's not files of particular commit. It's files of this commit if it will be melded with all previous commits.

Any ideas how to get list of such files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only tagName
```

would work, if you have set the tag in your repo.
That supposes that you have committed your index (with your added, removed and modified files).

A tag or commit will always references *all* the files of your repository, ie the full repository content.
It would not reference only what has been modified.